# Formula with differing output based on sign of input

Tags: functions

I'm looking for a mathematical formula that will reproduce this pseudo-code:

```
if x >= 0
  x+=1
else
  x-=1
```

If this is possible, what would such a formula look like?

Comment: $x+x/|x|$ works when $x\ne 0$. You'll probably have to deal with $x=0$ as a special case.

Comment: I see. That's perfect. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Of course if you look at the definitions of various mathematical functions such as $|x|$, they are often given in a multiple-line format, one line for each "case" of the input. See [this definition of the "sign" function,](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Sign.html) for example.

In this standard mathematical notation, your pseudocode could represent the
function $f$ defined as follows for real values $x$:

$$f(x) =
\begin{cases}
x + 1 & \mbox{if } x \geq 0 \\
x - 1 & \mbox{if } x < 0.
\end{cases}
$$

The part of your pseudocode that is mathematically awkward is not the `if x>=0`
part, but rather the `+=` and `-=` operations.
There is an extensive part of the literature of computer science devoted
to representing these and other assignment operations (including the
`=` operation of programming languages such as C++ and Java) mathematically.
The general consensus is that $x = x + 1$ is not a correct mathematical statement, so one puts a different symbol on the left side (sometimes on
both sides), for example, $$x' = x + 1,$$ $$x(t+1) = x(t) + 1,$$
or even something like
$$f(S) = (\lambda x.(x + 1))S,$$ where $S$ represents 
a state of the program's memory ("storage") 
and $f(S)$ the different state that results if you replace the value
stored at location $x$ with the value of $x + 1$.